# What is the most secure way to use jBCrypt?

Tags: java, hash, jbcrypt

I have been working on a login system in java. I currently have the program do some minor custom encryption first, then use JBCrypt to crypt/hash and then use php to check the database for matching hashes. However, the problem is that when using gensalt(n), you get a random salt everytime and therefore, the computed hash never matches the stored hash. Is there a good way to constrain the salt so that it hashes the same everytime? Or is it safe to retrieve my encrypted password before hashing from the db, and then use java to check that hash?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually quite simple. Store the salt or pre-salt in the db and just retrieve  that whenever needed.